# slide view below if list contains more data

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a list view in which data comes dynamically. I added the listView below some views. I want if there is data in my list view the view below listview should slide down.
right now it is not sliding down and my half listview is displayed.

Here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="65.3dp"
        android:layout_height="40.0dp"
        android:id="@+id/button_back"
        android:textColor="#ffada8a8"
        android:text="Back"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/Back_icon"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Booking Request"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="161.3dp"
        android:layout_height="34.5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button_back"
        android:id="@+id/lable_booking_request"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    <Button
        android:text="Submit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="34.5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/lable_booking_request"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="#ff000000"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff" />
    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45.8dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/button_back"
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#1E1E1E" />
    <Button
        android:text="New Booking"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/view1"
        android:id="@+id/lable_new_booking"
        android:layout_marginTop="-42dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/stylenew" />
    <Button
        android:text="Current Booking"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/lable_new_booking"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:textColor="#B361B3"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/style"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp" />
    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="44.0dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/view1"
        android:id="@+id/viewServiceType"
        android:background="#171717"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Select Service Type"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/view1"
        android:id="@+id/textselectuser"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/go"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/view1"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />
    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="44.0dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/viewServiceType"
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="#171717" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Pick Date &amp; Time"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/viewServiceType"
        android:id="@+id/textpickDateTime"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/view2"
        android:id="@+id/view3"
        android:background="#171717"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Select User"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/view2"
        android:id="@+id/textSelectUser"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
    <ListView
        android:layout_below="@id/view1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listViewSaloonUser"
        android:layout_marginTop="140dp" />
    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/listViewSaloonUser"
        android:id="@+id/view4"
        android:background="#171717" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Add/Edit Remainder"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/listViewSaloonUser"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@id/layoutlinear2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="152.0dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/view4">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="213.3dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="One day before appointment"
            android:id="@+id/servicetype1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="15dp" />
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/Unchecked"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/servicetype1"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="-23dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0.2dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/servicetype1"
            android:id="@+id/seperator"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:background="@drawable/hSeparator"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="194.7dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/seperator"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Add custom Remainder"
            android:id="@+id/servicetype2"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="15dp" />
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/Unchecked"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/servicetype1"
            android:id="@+id/imageviewunchecked"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0.2dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/imageviewunchecked"
            android:id="@+id/seperator2"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:background="@drawable/hSeparator"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="194.7dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/seperator2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Add Remainder to calender"
            android:id="@+id/servicetype2"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="15dp" />
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/add"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/servicetype2"
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-23dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="23dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I want if listview have any data  the view having `id=@+id/view4` should slide below.

Here is my Adapter code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<RelativeLayout 
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView
    android:text="Saloon User 1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_width="249.3dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textViewSaloonUser"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />
<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/Unchecked"
    android:layout_width="40.0dp"
    android:layout_height="20.0dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textViewSaloonUser"
    android:id="@+id/imageViewcheckbox"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp" />
<View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0.2dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/textViewSaloonUser"
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/hSeparator" />
```

can anyone tell me how to acheive this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should not have listView inside scroll view(Both are vertically scrollable).

Solution in your case would be to use only list view with header and footer:

create a layout header.xml and put following:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="65.3dp"
        android:layout_height="40.0dp"
        android:id="@+id/button_back"
        android:textColor="#ffada8a8"
        android:text="Back"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/Back_icon"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Booking Request"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="161.3dp"
        android:layout_height="34.5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button_back"
        android:id="@+id/lable_booking_request"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    <Button
        android:text="Submit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="34.5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/lable_booking_request"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="#ff000000"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff" />
    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45.8dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/button_back"
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#1E1E1E" />
    <Button
        android:text="New Booking"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/view1"
        android:id="@+id/lable_new_booking"
        android:layout_marginTop="-42dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/stylenew" />
    <Button
        android:text="Current Booking"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/lable_new_booking"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:textColor="#B361B3"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/style"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp" />
    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="44.0dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/view1"
        android:id="@+id/viewServiceType"
        android:background="#171717"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Select Service Type"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/view1"
        android:id="@+id/textselectuser"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/go"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/view1"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />
    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="44.0dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/viewServiceType"
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="#171717" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Pick Date &amp; Time"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/viewServiceType"
        android:id="@+id/textpickDateTime"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/view2"
        android:id="@+id/view3"
        android:background="#171717"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Select User"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/view2"
        android:id="@+id/textSelectUser"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

footer.xml:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="44dp"

        android:id="@+id/view4"
        android:background="#171717" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Add/Edit Remainder"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/listViewSaloonUser"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@id/layoutlinear2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="152.0dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/view4">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="213.3dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="One day before appointment"
            android:id="@+id/servicetype1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="15dp" />
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/Unchecked"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/servicetype1"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="-23dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0.2dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/servicetype1"
            android:id="@+id/seperator"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:background="@drawable/hSeparator"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="194.7dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/seperator"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Add custom Remainder"
            android:id="@+id/servicetype2"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="15dp" />
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/Unchecked"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/servicetype1"
            android:id="@+id/imageviewunchecked"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0.2dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/imageviewunchecked"
            android:id="@+id/seperator2"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:background="@drawable/hSeparator"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="194.7dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/seperator2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Add Remainder to calender"
            android:id="@+id/servicetype2"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="15dp" />
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/add"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/servicetype2"
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-23dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="23dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

main layout:

```
 <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_below="@id/view1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listViewSaloonUser"
        android:layout_marginTop="140dp" />
```

now in activity get the listview reference and inflate header and footer and do following:

```
listView.addHeaderView(headerView,null,false);
listView.addFooterView(footerView);
```